# How to manage messages in a xcode project?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, message

I'm a newbie in objective c.

I want to know what's the most common way to handle messages(or string format) in a xcode project.I mean, to put all the message strings or formats in one file to manage it easily.

Could anyone give me some advice??

Thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at localization options? It is usually a good idea to prepare your app or program for internationalization. The way this works is to have a file `Localizable.strings` where you have the exact text defined for each "text macro". The `strings` files (you have a version for each language) are in a very simple format:

```
// in en.lproj 
"Hello" = "Hello, World!"; 

// in de.lproj
"Hello" = "Hallo, Welt!"
```

Just make sure in your code you consistently use this format for literal strings that are displayed anywhere in your user interface:

```
label.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Hello", @"Optional comment");
```